# I can't login to magento admin panel

Tags: php, magento

I have a live running website developed using magento **(magento version is 1.8.1.0)**.Everything is fine but sometimes i am issuing problems in back end login. When i am login it doesn't showing any error message but simply redirecting to https://example-store/index.php/admin/index/index/key/bed7fg4dfdfdsd45th0bddfg3gfde/..

I researched about this and i commented some lines in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php.

```
//if (!$cookieParams['httponly']) {
//unset($cookieParams['httponly']);
//if (!$cookieParams['secure']) {
//unset($cookieParams['secure']);
//if (!$cookieParams['domain']) {
//unset($cookieParams['domain']);
//}
//}
//}
//if (isset($cookieParams['domain'])) {
//$cookieParams['domain'] = $cookie->getDomain();
//}
```

Even after i am facing same issue..

Answer (score 0):

This is the default admin panel url route:

> https://example-store/index.php/admin

If you set it to be custom you may have an issue with your core_config_data or cache flush issues.

Investigate the values inside `core_config_data`:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
core_config_data
WHERE path LIKE '%web%'
```

And ensure you remove your cache in `root/var/cache` and `root/var/full_page_cache` ( if using EE )

Comment: i made changes in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php. // `session cookie params
        $cookieParams = array(
            'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
            'path'     => $cookie->getPath()
            /* 'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
            'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
            'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly() */
        );` now its working fine....